# Wordpress Customizer API: access variables

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have the following code:

```
function color_scheme_customizer_register($wp_customize) {

  $wp_customize->add_section('front_page', array(
    'title'    => __('Front Page'),
    'priority' => 120,
  ));
  // MAIN IMAGE
  $wp_customize->add_setting('front_page_options[image_select]', array(
    'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
    'type'           => 'option',
  ));
  $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control($wp_customize, 'image_select', array(
    'label'    => __('Main Image', 'themename'),
    'section'  => 'front_page',
    'settings' => 'front_page_options[image_select]',
  )));

  // FEATURE ONE
  $wp_customize->add_setting('front_page_options[feature_one_page]', array(
    'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
    'type'           => 'option',
  ));
  $wp_customize->add_control('feature_one_page', array(
    'label'      => __('Featured Page One'),
    'section'    => 'front_page',
    'settings'   => 'front_page_options[feature_one_page]',
    'type'           => 'dropdown-pages',
  ));
  $wp_customize->add_setting('front_page_options[feature_one_textarea]', array(
    'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
    'type'           => 'option',
  ));
  $wp_customize->add_control('feature_one_textarea', array(
    'label'      => __('Featured Page One Summary'),
    'section'    => 'front_page',
    'settings'   => 'front_page_options[feature_one_textarea]',
    'type'           => 'textarea',
  ));
  ...
}
```

I want to access the front_page_array variables, but all I can find is documentation on simply creating a new .css spreadsheet to make changes. Is there a way I can specifically access the variables like so:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php get_customizer_variables('front_page_options'); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve values that you have stored, you will either use get_theme_mod() or get_option(), depending on the "type" you set. If no type is given, it defaults to theme_mod. To retrieve a field, use something like:

```
get_option( 'front_page_options[image_select]', '' );
```

Alternatively, if you have multiple options, you can retrieve all of them in an array and then access them as needed.

```
$front_page_options = get_option( 'front_page_options', '' );
$image_select = $front_page_options['image_select'];
```

This is a very simple example but should give you an idea of how to access the values you are looking for.

Comment: Wow! You are seriously the best! I have been trying to use get_theme_mod() and couldn't figure out why it wasn't working! Are there any benefits to using get_theme_mod() vs get_option()?

Comment: Glad to help. From a performance perspective, get_option() will be the better choice because if you look at the get_theme_mod function (wp-includes/theme.php,) get_theme_mod() actually calls get_theme_mod() which in turn calls get_option(). Clearly, calling get_option will be the more efficient route.